# how to show gridlines on hAxis in google chart tool AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

I want to show the gridlines on hAxis in google chart tool AngularJS.
This is my code:

$scope.donneesGraphe = {};

```
    $scope.dataGraphe.type = 'LineChart';

    $scope.dataGraphe.data = {
        "cols": myCols,
        "rows": myRows
    };

    $scope.dataGraphe.options = {
        title: "",
        pointSize: 6,
        pointShape: 'round',
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Tiempo (hora)',
            gridlines: {
                color: '#F00'
            }
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Distancia (km)',
            gridlines: {
                color: '#F00'
            }
        }
    };
```

I only see the gridlines on vAxis.

I use the version: 0.0.8

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

`hAxis.gridlines`, this option is only supported for a continuous axis. From [Customizing Axes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes):

> - For a discrete axis, set the data column type to string.
> - For a continuous axis, set the data column type to one of: number, date, datetime or timeofday.